Utility to generate TMS tile structure from arbitrary image
I'm looking for utility to generate TMS tile directory structure from PNG/JPEG image. Result would used as overlay over a map. Input data is the image file, north-south-west-east coordinates (WGS84) image is representing, angle to rotate image before processing further and zoom levels to generate. Only tiles covering input image shall be created.
Already searched and studied GDAL but didn't figure out if it suits for my needs (it probably does).

Did you find gdal2tiles https://gdal.org/en/stable/programs/gdal2tiles.html? The source image must be georeferenced but by your description the case is simple enough for gdal_edit and -a_ulurll https://gdal.org/en/stable/programs/gdal_edit.html#cmdoption-a_ulurll

Thanks @user30184 ! Yes, I found gdal2tiles before asking. I believe your advice gave me the missing glue to put pieces together. Need to familiarize myself with gdal and get gdal installed (already tried and failed on my Ubuntu based env). Continuing ...

sudo apt install gdal-bin or use conda. Don't use pip unless you really know what you're doing as it's just a source package, not compiled and you'll need to install all the required development packages and compiler

Thanks @user2856, yes - pip method was nightmare, apt method went fine. My workflow is now as:
gdal_translate -of Gtiff -a_ullr <ulx> <uly> <lrx> <lry> <src_dataset> <dst_dataset>
gdal_edit.py -mo DATUM=WGS84 -a_ulurll <ulx> <uly> <urx> <ury> <llx> <lly> <dst_dataset>
gdal2tiles.py -z 12-17 --xyz -s EPSG:4326 -w none <dst_dataset> <output_dir>

This gives me decent result.
